# Change Android CalendarView arrow color/icon and replace selected circle shape

Tags: android, android-styles

Is it possible to change color of prev/next arrows in `CalendarView` or replace with a different icon image (set a different drawable somehow)?

Also is it possible to change selected shape (also set a different drawable)?

[image]

Comment: any update about that? u could do it with one from android sdk?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
    new DatePickerBuilder(this, listener).previousButtonSrc(R.drawable.drawable) // for drawable of the previous arrow
    .forwardButtonSrc(R.drawable.drawable) // for drawable of the forward arrow
```

and also check these :
[Is possible to hide arrows and put some imageView between title of calendar and weekdays?](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/issues/167)

and
[Material Calendar View](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)

there are open source calendars which are more flexible.

Comment: no, thanks. I want to use `CalendarView` from Android SDK